# mongodb OperationFailure...

Tags: python, mongodb

When I try to to use new Aggregate framework from Python I got the next message:

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', 'call_log'), ('pipeline', [{'$project': {u'date': '1', u'status': '1', u'number': '1', u'description': '1'}}])]) failed: exception: field path references must be prefixed with a '$' ("1"
```

The python's code:

```
db.command('aggregate', 'test_collection', pipe_line=[{'$project':{u'date': '1', u'status': '1', u'number': '1', u'description': '1'}}])
```

What does this message means? Where's the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, you should write not `'1'`, but `1`. `'1'` (with quotes) is interpreted as string, which causes error.